# Weird exceptions when running a .NET DLL from NI TestStand, but in VS2019 it works smoothly

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, signalr.client, teststand

I'm trying to run my app which includes some SignalR connections and other async methods.

As soon as the codes reaches

```
connection.StartAsync();
```

I get this Error:

> System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.Constants' threw an exception.'
>
> Inner Exception:
> FormatException: The format of value '@BuiltBy: dlab-DDVSOWINAGE059 @Branch: release/2.1 @SrcCode: [https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/30ab651fcb4354552bd4891619a0bdd81e0ebdbf'](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/30ab651fcb4354552bd4891619a0bdd81e0ebdbf%27) is invalid.
>
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> System.Net.Http.Headers.ProductInfoHeaderValue.Parse(string)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.Constants.Constants()

When running from VS all looks good and works fine.

So far, I have no clue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looking at the source i can see that in the Constants class the UserAgent Header gets prepared for later usage in requests. As part of the UserAgent string the AssemblyInformationalVersion of the SignalR Assembly is used. Without knowing anything about TestStand i would assume that this product manipulates the Attribute in a way that makes it invalid to be used as UserAgent string. Therefore you get a FormatException.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. So, there's nothing I can do about it?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. @Israel Did you find the solution?